# Broken return type declarations in PHP7?

Tags: php-7

I can't do something like this:

```
$a = 5;
function a():int use($a) {
 return $a + 5;
}
```

Do return type declaration break scope inheritance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only use the `use` keyword for inheriting variables in **anonymous** functions (closures). This has nothing to do with the declared return type.

See http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php

To clarify a bit here is an example:

```
$a = 1;
$func = function () use ( $a ) {
    return $a + 1;
}
// Call the closure that has captured $a
$func();
```

Comment: Ahh... I see. Named functions are just functions. They are not first class citizents like anonymous functions? This is not the case in JS so I got confused.

Comment: Yes, php is archaic when it comes to such things ;)

Comment: There are no first class citizens in PHP :P

Comment: Yeah. We are thinking the same things... I tried the example provided just a litle bit before you posted it :P At least I now know how to write my functions...Thanks for great answer..